# Google Script: How to get Recurring Events from Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, recurring-events

There's a popular script on various websites that allows one to easily export Google Calendar events to a Google Spreadsheet.  It works fine ... except that it does not work with recurring events.

Here's the crux of the code:

```
var mycal = "sample@gmail.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
```

Then one just needs to iterate through the members of 'events'.  The problem appears to be that recurring events are defined in another way which 'getEvents' does not understand.  Thus a query of a date range containing only recurring events finds nothing.

I'm wondering if anyone has written some code that would properly query for recurring events?

Robert

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not correct, recurring events are returned exactly as any other ones.

I don't know what script you use but if you can't get the recurring events then I guess this script is just not good.

I'm not going to publish the whole code here because the version I use is a bit long but you can make a copy of this spreadsheet and test it yourself.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0uAYz7fAChbnhIfWwy-xYluomDsfkqblBRHcGNwThY/edit?usp=sharing

*Run opOpen once from the menu to get the authorization then use the spreadsheet menu. You'll get a UI that will ask you to define which calendar to use and the start / end dates. These values will be stored in properties for next usage.*

Answer (score 0):

Serge, you're correct, it does handle recurring deliveries.  My failure was to include the start time and end time in addition to the date.  Once I did that, via a simple string concatenation, then all worked properly.

Thank you for your feedback!

Robert